# php - check for endless possibility and stop when reach the end

Tags: php, logic

I got a folder structure like so

```
css
  main.css
  home
    layout.css
    menu.css
    ...
  account
    user.css
    menu.css
      user
        user.css
        level
          time.css
          ...
        ...
```

You can see a lot of files and folders nested in each other. I want loop through folder css, read every files and folders in it. If a file, run function do(), if a folder run function make() and continue to loop through that folder to check for files and folders inside. Repeat the process until there are no more folder and file left to loop through.

I can easily loop through the files and folders if I know how exactly how many there are. The problem is I don't know how many folders and files there are. So there need to be a special technique to archive what I want ?

Comment: You need to iterate through your files/folders recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be perfect for the [RecursiveDirectorIterator](https://www.php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) class that comes with PHP. It'll loop through each file and folder recursively. Each item that you iterate through will be a subclass of [`SplFileInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) which contains many function you can use (e.g. getBasename(), getCTime(), getExtension(), and many more).

```
<?php 

$dir = '/path/to/folder';

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

foreach ( $iterator as $path )
{
  // If it's a directory.
  if ($path->isDir())
  {
    // Do something.
  }
  else
  {
    // Do something else.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine if you had a function processDir() you could call which given a directory would loop through the files and folder in that directory.

For each file, it might call processFile(), but for each *directory* it finds, it calls itself - i.e. processDir()

That's an example of a recursive function, and is one way to solve your problem.

Here's an (untested!) example of what I mean...

```
function processDir($dir) {
   $d = dir($dir);
   while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
       if ($entry[0]=='.')
           continue;

       $full=$d->path.$entry;
       if (is_dir($full))
           processDir($full); //recursive call
       else
           processFile($full);
    }
    $d->close();
}
```

A recursive function isn't the only way to do this, it's just a technique to add to your arsenal. It would be easy to change this to have an array based queue of directories, seeded with the top level directory, which you process until empty. Each time you come across a subdirectory, you push it on the queue.

Now, hopefully that's illustrated some useful answers to the 'how do I process a tree of unknown breadth and depth'. But for the case of directory scanning, PHP5 provides the rather nice [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) class, which is nicely explored in some of the other answers on this page.

Comment: Oh look at me rocking it old school. I've been using PHP for over a decade and the cool kids use RecursiveDirectorIterator now :)

Comment: It's definitely a little easier than the old-school method but both are just as good. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this easily using a recursive function (which calls itself on every directory), or using the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a recursive algorithm to loop through your files and folders. See [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=136482) for an example in pseudo-code which should be pretty simple to implement in php.

The basic concept in recursion is a function which (given certain conditions) calls itself.